# Return a variable as a property in an IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I am trying to return a variable set after the initialization of an IIFE as a property. The issue is if I bind the variable directly, I get an empty object. If I bind it through a function, I get my desired result.

```js
var Application = (function(){

    var localInformation = {};

    function init(){
        localInformation = _demoApiCall();
    }

    function _demoApiCall(){
        // Pretend this method isn't here, and returns a complex object
        return {
            name: "Demo"
        }
    }

    function doWork(){
        // localInformation is properly structured here if called
    }

    return {
        Init: init,
        DoWork: doWork,
        InfoProp: localInformation, // returns {}
        InfoMethod: function(){
            return localInformation; // returns {name:"demo"}
        }
    }

})();

Application.Init();

console.log(Application.InfoProp);
console.log(Application.InfoMethod());
```

After initially calling `Application.Init()` on document ready, the example will only work if I call `var inf = Application.InfoMethod()`, however it would be much cleaner if I could call `var info = Application.InfoProp`.

I've tried to read up on JS Closures, but haven't gotten any information into why there would be no proper reference to the private variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you meant to write `localInformation` in your returned object.

The problem is that you are re-assigning the `localInformation` variable name to a new object.

```
localInformation = _demoAPICall()
```

Meaning that your `InfoProp` property points to the initial value of `localInformation` (the empty object), while within the function, you get the latest value of `localInformation`.

You have two options:

1) Extend the existing object instead of assigning the variable name to a new one:

```
extend(localInformation, _demoApiCall())
```

You cann use jQuery's extend, ot the one from lodash, or any other implementation will do.

2) use a getter method

```
return {
  Init: Init,
  get InfoProp () { return information },
  ....
}
```

Comment: I was meant to write `localInformation`, however I've updated my example to have running code. I've never seen the `get` keyword in a return, will definitely use it if it works. Would you mind explaining what it does it's more maniacal than it suggests?

Comment: MDN explains it better than I ever could: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Looks like you can't use `get` before the reference name. It basically works for me if I use it like this:
`Context: {get Current(){
            return current;
        }}`

Comment: Just to add - If you assign the results `_demoApiCall()` on an object member instead of whole object it would not create a second object it would use the same like  `function init(){ localInformation.foo = _demoApiCall();}`