# Create a setter for a local variable in a Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code

```
var loyaltyObject = (function () {
  var data = null, vm, getLoyaltyUrl;

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: getLoyaltyUrl,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (resp) {
        data = resp;
      },
      error: function (resp) {
        console.log('Error fetching offers!');
        console.log(resp);
      }// error(resp)
    });// $.ajax()  
  }

...

  vm = {
    getData: getData,
    getLoyaltyUrl: getLoyaltyUrl
  };

  return vm;
}());
```

on document.ready I call

```
function Init() {
    window.loyaltyObject.getLoyaltyUrl = '@Url.Action("GetLoyaltyData", "Orders")';
    window.loyaltyObject.getData();
}
```

`window.loyaltyObject.getLoyaltyUrl`  is indeed the url but the internal `getLoyaltyUrl` is still undefined.

I read the following [return a variable as a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542683/return-a-variable-as-a-property-in-an-iife) about setting up a getter, but how would I perform a setter, what is the `this` or `value` I would be setting?

Also would it be comparable on most browsers?

Comment: FWIW, I think there is an expectations that properties which start with `get...` are actually functions.

Comment: What's the reason for not making the URL a parameter of `getData`?

Comment: `vm` has getLoyaltyUrl as a (public) property, no need for a setter.  Or do you want to set it on  `loyaltyObject`?

Comment: Just use the `this.getLoyaltyUrl` property inside the method and drop the local variable.

Comment: @FelixKling can't give you a good one.

Comment: Making the URL a parameter seems to be more natural to me. It's more expressive. "I want to load data from this URL" vs "Set this property to a URL and then get the data".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value to `vm.getLoyaltyUrl` not to the private variable `getLoyaltyUrl`. That variable has no inheritance from the object `vm` so it never ever gets defined in your code

Just change:

```
url: getLoyaltyUrl
```

to

```
url: vm.getLoyaltyUrl
```

Simplified example

```js
var loyaltyObject = (function () {
  var data = null, vm;

  function getData() {
   // switched out the ajax for a simple console.log()
   console.log(vm.getLoyaltyUrl)
  }

  vm = {
    getData: getData,
    getLoyaltyUrl: null
  };

  return vm;
}());
// following is exactly what you have
function Init() {
    window.loyaltyObject.getLoyaltyUrl = '@Url.Action("GetLoyaltyData", "Orders")';
    window.loyaltyObject.getData();
}

Init()
```

Answer (score 1):

> but how would I perform a setter, what is the `this` or `value` I would be setting?

You would simply assign to the variable `getLoyaltyUrl`:

```
vm = {
  // ...
  set getLoyaltyUrl(value) {
    getLoyaltyUrl = value;
  },
}
```

You wouldn't use `this` in your case. `value` is the value assigned to the property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any need for a custom property here. But you can look into Object.defineProperty or it's Reflect counterpart to change objects properties on the fly.

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'getLoyaltyUrl', {
    set: (value) => {
        // do something here, better be worth it.
    },
    get: () => {}
})
```